# How to pass a struct by reference?

Tags: c++, queue

I can't figure it out, this is what I have so far.

But the function `Enqueue()` is not changing the `Head` & `Tail` objects from the main method.

How do I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct queuenode{
    int data;
    struct queuenode *next;
} Queue_type;

void Enqueue( Queue_type *head, Queue_type *tail , int item)
{
    Queue_type *temp;
    temp->data = item;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (tail == NULL){//if first node
        head=temp;
        tail=temp;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    Queue_type *Head;
    Queue_type *Tail;

    Head = NULL;
    Tail = NULL;

    printf("\n[*]Enter Number to Enqueue : ");
    scanf("%d", &item);
    Enqueue(Head, Tail, item);

}
```

Comment: There is an additional issue of not allocating memory for your Queue_type objects.

Comment: I don't see where you are passing anything by reference. Can you be more specific? Do you mean to pass a pointer to it?

Comment: If you happen to pass by the options dialog set your editor to expand tabs to spaces...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to pass a pointer by reference? Pass it by reference:

```
void Enqueue( Queue_type *&head, Queue_type *&tail , int item)
```

Other problems:

```
Queue_type *temp;
temp->data = item;
```

is undefined behavior.

[Mandatory link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) You're writing C code in a C++ environment. Just don't.